# SQL: Update columns and reference these columns in the same update?

Tags: sql, sql-update

What happens in this case, assuming `col1` has initially the value of 10:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET col1 = 20,
    col2 = col1 + 10
```

Will `col2` be 20 or 30 after the update?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

It will be 20 according to the rules of standard SQL.  The new values do not get committed until the end of the `update` statement.  They are not committed row-by-row or column-by-column.  Remember the ACID properties of databases -- all the changes take effect at the same time.

It is possible that some database out there does not behave this way.  It is easy enough to check in practice.

Comment: MySQL will not produce this result.

Answer (score 1):

The column will show 20

the Update function is running as a bulk.

you can do this quick test:

```
/* Create Test Table
select 
10 as col1,
0 as col2
into TestTable
*/

/* update 
update TestTable
set col1 = 20,
col2 = col1 + 10
*/

select * from TestTable
```